# Search for the course “Java 101” in courses2 and print out the index of the course in the List

Tags: java

**Search for the course “Java 101” in courses2  and print out the index of the  course in the List.**
I am not sure how to implement this request in my code below. All of the code thus far works. Everything is implemented correctly. I just require help with writing the above asked code. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Course {
  String courseName; // declare variables
  int numOfStudents;
  String courseLecturer;

  Course(
      String courseName,
      int numOfStudents,
      String courseLecturer) { // constructor that constructs course object
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.numOfStudents = numOfStudents;
    this.courseLecturer = courseLecturer;
  }

  public void setCourseName(String courseName) { // set method for courseName
    courseName = courseName;
  }

  public String getCourseName() { // get method for courseName
    return courseName;
  }

  public void setNumOfStudents(int numOfStudents) { // set method for numOfStudents
    numOfStudents = numOfStudents;
  }

  public int getNumOfStudents() { // get method for numOfStudents
    return numOfStudents;
  }

  public void setCourseLecturer(String courseLecturer) { // set method for courseLecturer
    courseLecturer = courseLecturer;
  }

  public String getcourseLecturer() { // get method for courseLecturer
    return courseLecturer;
  }

  public String toString() { // toString method
    return "CourseName: "
        + courseName
        + " Number of Students: "
        + numOfStudents
        + " Course Lecturer: "
        + courseLecturer;
  }

  public static Comparator<Course> courseNameComparator =
      new Comparator<Course>() {

        public int compare(Course c1, Course c2) {
          String cs1 = c1.getCourseName().toUpperCase();
          String cs2 = c2.getCourseName().toUpperCase();

          return cs1.compareTo(cs2);
        }
      };

  public static Comparator<Course> studentsComparator =
      new Comparator<Course>() {

        public int compare(Course c1, Course c2) {

          int s1 = c1.getNumOfStudents();
          int s2 = c2.getNumOfStudents();

          return s1 - s2;
        }
      };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // adding 5 courses to course1 using add method
    ArrayList<Course> course1 = new ArrayList<Course>();
    course1.add(new Course("C", 10, "Jesse"));
    course1.add(new Course("Python", 21, "Joe"));
    course1.add(new Course("C++", 8, "Mary"));
    course1.add(new Course("C#", 26, "Jenny"));
    course1.add(new Course("Java", 24, "Jack"));

    for (Course c : course1) {
      System.out.println(c);
    }

    Collections.sort(course1, Course.studentsComparator);
    for (Course c : course1) {
      System.out.println(c);
    }
    // swap elements
    Collections.swap(course1, 1, 2);
    for (Course c : course1) {
      System.out.println(c);
    }

    ArrayList<Course> course2 = new ArrayList<Course>(); // new ArrayList created for course2
    course2.addAll(course1); // addAll method to add courses in course1 to course2
    for (Course c : course2) {
      System.out.println(c);
    }
    // use the add method to add two elements to course2
    course2.add(new Course("Java 101", 55, "Dr.P Green"));
    course2.add(new Course("Advanced Programming", 93, "Prof.M Milton"));
    for (Course c : course2) {
      System.out.println(c);
    }
    Collections.sort(
        course2,
        Course.courseNameComparator); // sorting the courses in course2 into alphabetical order
    for (Course c : course2) {
      System.out.println(c);
    }
    boolean isCommon = Collections.disjoint(course1, course2); // disjoint method
    System.out.println("No Common elements: " + isCommon);
    Collections.sort(course2, Course.studentsComparator);
    System.out.println("Course with minimum number of students: ");
    System.out.println(course2.get(0));
    System.out.println("Course with maximum number of students: ");
    System.out.println(course2.get(course2.size() - 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: You want a for-loop to iterate over all courses in courses2. In the loop you check if "Java 101" is the courseName. If this is the case, print the index of the course in the array. - Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate the whole list and compare the course name with the given string. When found just break the loop.

```
int index=-1;
for(int i=0;i<course2.size();i++)
{
if(course2.get(i).getCourseName().equals("JAVA")
{
index=i;
break;
}
}
```

This is a long way to do it. You can also find the object index in the list by 
indexOf() function. It will return -1 if the searched object is not found in the list.